# Random Gaussian with standard deviation

Tags: python, neural-network, gaussian, basis

I want to intialize a array with random gaussian with standard deviation of 0.08 in python. 
I was able to find something like this

```
self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
```

However it for standard deviation of 1.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
help(np.random.randn)
```

> Notes
>       -----
>       For random samples from :math:`N(\mu, \sigma^2)`, use:
>       `sigma * np.random.randn(...) + mu`